# Service doesn't receive intent / extras

Tags: android, service, android-intent, extras

I just can't get what's wrong here.

**Activity.java:**

```
...
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, Service.class);
intent.putExtra(Service.KEY_TEST, "123456789");
startService(intent);
...
```

**Service.java:**

```
...
private Intent intent;
public static final String KEY_TEST;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("TEST", intent.getStringExtra(KEY_TEST)); // when I remove this line,
    // it works, otherwise gives NullPointerException and FC's
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.intent = intent;
    return START_STICKY;
}
...
```

The Service clearly doesn't receive the extras sent from the Activity. When I try to get any extras I sent before, the app force closes and LogCat gives NullPointerException. When I remove the line where I try to get the extras, the app doesn't force close, but I don't obviously receive the extras either.

Comment: what errors do you get? What happens? What doesnt happen? Its hard to tell what you want with the question.

Comment: Read the title of my question and my comment in the code. The line `Log.d...` force closes the app. LogCat is whining about NullPointerException, so the extras are not received. When I remove the line there's no force close but I obviously don't receive my extras either.

Comment: You should write it specifically in your question, not in the title or in the code block.

Comment: I thought everybody was supposed to read the title and contents of questions here. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put this line `Log.d("TEST", intent.getStringExtra(KEY_TEST));` in,

`onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` method..

**EDIT:**

For more info how the service life cyclces follows, Look at this [Service Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle).

Comment: I can't believe I made such a noob move. I guess that's what happens after 3 hours of non-stop coding. Works like a charm.

Comment: There was the 3 minute time limit before I could accept your question. Why doesn't receiving extras work in onCreate in my case?

Comment: Because your intent is received by service in onStartCommand() method, not in onCreate() that's why. Happy Coding.. :-)

Comment: onStartCommand still gets fired before onCreate, right? I'm confused why I can't set the intent variable in onStartCommand and use it in onCreate.

Comment: look at the link I provided in answer. You will get better understanding on how service works.

Answer (score 0):

onStartCommand() happens after onCreate() method.